# PIN - get process ID for the Binary being instrumented?

Tags: c++, c, binaryfiles, instrumentation, intel-pin

Hi does anyone know how to get the process ID for the binary that is being instrumented by PIN? So for example if I have something like:

```
pin -t MyTool -- somebinary
```

How do I get the process ID for 'somebinary' inside the PINTool that I'm trying to write. I checked the documentation but there doesn't seem to be anything I can use, or maybe I've overlooked something?
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you attach to pid instead using `-pid <pid #>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can directly use getpid()? This is how I do when making Pin tools.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html

Pin also provides process related APIs

http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/62732/Pin/html/group__PIN__PROCESS__API.html